# for statement from dictionary, python

Tags: python, dictionary

Basically, I am new to programming and I sign up for a python course. I receive an exercise asking as follow:

Build a function that returns, given an arbitrary birth year, the Chinese zodiac sign corresponding to that calendar year. You start from a dictionary of Chinese zodiac signs from 2001-2012 (covering the whole 12-sign cycle)

So my idea is to create a dictionary,

```
d={2001:'Snake',2002:'Horse',2003:'Goat',2004:'Monkey',2005:'Rooster',2006:'Dog',
           2007:'Pig',2008:'Rat',2009:'Ox',2010:'Tiger',2011:'Rabbit',2012:'Dragon'}
```

And I begin with the for statement

```
def year(x):
    for x in d.keys:
        if x=d.keys:
            print d.value
        else:
        x..
```

I basically have no idea how to approach the next step. Can someone please me some direction?

Comment: You don't have to check the keys manually, that's the whole point of using a dictionary. Simply writing `return d[x]` will return the zodiac sign. If you are concerned that `x` might not be in your dictionary at all, you should use `return d.get(x, None)` (replace `None` with any default value you want to return for years not found in the dict).

Comment: What does `x%12` do? Can you find a way to use modulos to convert an arbitrary x to a value between 2001 and 2012?

Comment: Also note that your function is called `year`, however, it is always better to choose meaningful names such as `get_chinese_zodiac_sign(year)`.

Comment: Frist thing, thank you for your reply. But again I want a return "Horse" when I enter year(2024), in which 2024 is 12 more than 2002 and it is not in the dictionary

Comment: `%` is the modulo operator.  It gives you the remainder of what you'd get if you divided the first term by the second term.  Another way to look at it is that `A % N` turns any number `A` into a number in the range `0..(N-1)`.  As @JakobLovern points out, you can use this, with `N = 12` (and a little more math) to turn any year into one of the keys in your dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. You can create a dictionary to store the Chinese Zodiac Signs. Since there are 12 of them and to make the math easier, let's get the modulus value of 12 for each year. That makes mod 0 = Monkey,... mod 11 = Goat.

With that, you can do year % 12 will result with a number that we can use to extract the value from the dictionary `d`. The way to extract the value from the dictionary is `dict[key]`. In our case it will be `d[0]` will give `Monkey`.

With that, we can write the program as follows:

```
#define the dictionary with keys. Numbers 0 thru 11 as keys and Zodiac sign as values

d={0:'Monkey',1:'Rooster',2:'Dog',3:'Pig',4:'Rat',5:'Ox',
   6:'Tiger',7:'Rabbit',8:'Dragon',9:'Snake',10:'Horse',11:'Goat'}

#define a function that receives the birth year, then returns the Zodiac sign
#as explained earlier we do dict[key]
#year%12 will give the key to use

def chinese_yr(cy):
    return d[cy%12]

#get an input from the user. To ensure the value is an int,
#use the statement within a try except statement
while True:
    try:
        yr = int(input ('enter year :'))
        break
    except:
        print ('Invalid entry. Please enter year')

#call the function with the year as argument        
print (chinese_yr(int(yr)))
```

The output of this will be:

```
enter year :2011
Rabbit

enter year :2001
Snake

enter year :2020
Rat

enter year :2021
Ox
```

Comment: sorry, I just missed your answer because I was struggling to understand what response try to tell me. Your answer is far better than what I ask for. Thank you for your coding and effort.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, thank you to Jakob and Steve, I have never thought of using modulus. So I adjusted my dictionary and my coded.

```
d={9:'Snake',10:'Horse',11:'Goat',0:'Monkey',1:'Rooster',2:'Dog',
           3:'Pig',4:'Rat',5:'Ox',6:'Tiger',7:'Rabbit',8:'Dragon'}

def get_Chinese_zodiac(x):
for x in d:
    x=x%12
return d[x]
```

Funny thing is, my code can only return "Dragon".

Comment: You are iterating through the dictionary so it is getting values 9, 10, 11, 0, .... 8. The last value you got is 8. so d[8] is Dragon. Whatever you do, the result will always be Dragon. See my implementation to understand how to use modulus. You need to use it on the year not on the dictionary key